# Сборка демонстрационных проектов Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, c++

Собираю проекты из Android NDK: http://mikelsv.livejournal.com/826.html

Устанавливаю собранный пакет, появляется иконка.
Проблема в том, что нажав на иконку, открывается окно с надписью: Hello World, %parogram_name%.
Собирал bitmap-plasma, hello-neon и другие, у всех одна и та же реакция.

Что у вас делают эти программы? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Опишите свои действия для начала. Что делали, какой тулзой собирали. У меня все эти примеры прекрасно работают, собирал ndk-build. Ставил все по инструкции.

Comment: ndk-build, android create project, ant, ant debug, adb.
По какой инструкции, дайте ссылку?

Comment: Пожалуйста - http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 1):

На примере bitmap-plasma на Ubuntu:

```
emulator -avd sample
android update project --target 1 --path .
ndk-build
ant debug
adb install Plasma-debug.apk
```

Клик по иконке в эмуляторе и после этого появляется картинка, по виду похожая на плазму.

Если повторить то же самое для hello-neon с настройками по умолчанию, то будет окно, в котором написано (с некоторой задержкой):

> FIR Filter benchmark:
> C version: 9570.77 ms
> Neon version: Not an ARMv7 CPU !

Comment: Собираю в windows, шаги те же результат непонятный. поделитесь собранным проектом, хочу увидеть, что работает и посмотреть разницу между проектами.